# How to access previous versions of a Google Docs document

Tags: google-workspace

We are working simultaneously on some text document using google docs. After one week we need to check some changes so just tried "revision history" (which worked at the beginning) but now it does not work. We tried different browsers and operating systems but it crashes.

I would be happy if at least I could get the last version and some other one, so using another "diff" tool I could check the changes. But right now I do not know how to access a previous version. Is it there any way to do this?

Comment: Is this with standard Google accounts (i.e. @gmail.com), or **Google Apps** accounts? Google Apps have a lower priority when it comes to updates and bug fixes, strangely enough.

Comment: Also, if you were serious about keeping track of changes, I'd recommend a setup with utilizes cloud sharing and a revision control tool (e.g. Dropbox + Mercurial (with TortoiseHg) is fairly user-friendly).

Comment: i did not came here to get the opinion about whether this is a good approach or not. personally I dislike most of the google products and its philosophy. the situation was imposed by our boss, so can not do any other thing but just solve the situation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open any document
2. Select `File` > `See revision history`.

Comment: obviously you did not read the question and what I did before

Comment: This is the only way to see previous versions of a file. If your browser is crashing, try looking into the error console. But in that case the title of your question is irrelevant. Change it to something like "browser is crashing while opening docs revision". You'll get better answers.

Comment: That I accepted the answer as good does not mean my problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Next to simply using `File` > `Version history` there is the following way. Google docs has an API with access to the version history. See question [Import Google Docs document revision history into a Git repository?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/25592/244766) and answers therein for utilities that can export this version history.